# saving a specific activity through intent

Tags: android

I have a main activity that has a start button that will intent to the next page(2nd activity) then from that 2nd activity there's a button also that will intent to the next page (3rd activity), my question is

1.how can I save the 3rd activity after 2nd activity intent to it?

2.If I exit the app and open it again, the start button on my main activity should intent me to the 3rd activity and not on the 2nd activity

Answer (score 0):

Do you call `finish()` between the transitions? You should not. Android stores the `Activity` stack for you so when the user comes back into the app all three (1, 2, 3) activities will be on the stack.

Now, for jumping from 1st -> 3rd instead of going 1st -> 2nd -> 3rd you could store a flag that the 1st `Activity` will check. If the flag is present then call `startActivity(Intent intent)` for the 3rd activity directly.

Another way is to have 2nd `Activity` check that flag in `onCreate()` and if its present immediately start the 3rd `Activity`. Make sure to call `finish()` in `onCreate()` since this will avoid the rest of the lifecycle methods (`onStart()` `onResume()` etc.) to execute.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Im trying to save Activity 3 after the intent so that every time the user exits the application, then open it again, when he press the start button it should intent to the 3rd activity this time and it should not pass 2nd activity